# C++ OpenGL - 2D Lighting Around Object in a Pitch-Black Environment

Tags: opengl, c++, lighting

I am making a 2D game in C++ with OpenGL where a maze is generated and you have to move the character through the maze and get it to the end. I have achieved all this, but now I want to make it more challenging by having everything pitch-black but a small light around the character. How can I achieve this? I don't want the light to be complicated and I don't want it to only go through the tunnels. I just want a simple light around the character to illuminate that area of the maze.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stencil buffer:

https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Stencil_buffer
http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Stencil-testing

This is what you are looking for?